# Why does the Area 51 "Commit" dialog require my real name?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

I am somewhat concerned about my online privacy, and as such do not give out any personally identifying information to any online site. I thus ask, why do you want my real name?

Comment: Agreed, a confirmation e-mail should be enough to check whether you're serious. Besides, it's completely useless: there's just *no way* to know if someone is *actually* putting his/her real name in there.